# jmeter: can function FileToString(path) take two dynamic values to path

Tags: jmeter

I need to append two dynamic values to build the path.
one from CSV the other from user-defined vars.

So I've tried this on a lot of permutations. non seems to work.

`${__FileToString(${PATH}/${__eval(${NAME})},,)}`

what does work was:

`${__FileToString(/my/path/to/files/${__eval(${snapshot})},,)}`

So I'm guessing it has to do with my syntax.

how do I use __FileToString with two vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy:

```
${__FileToString(${PATH}/${__eval(${NAME})},,)}
```

should work, syntactically your expression is correct.

Moreover, if your CSV file doesn't contain any nested [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) references you don't need this [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) call at all and can simplify your function to:

```
${__FileToString(${PATH}/${NAME},,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

So double check that your `${PATH}` and especially `${NAME}` variable have anticipated values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

If you're uncertain regarding specific function syntax - just use [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)